# Android Code for Refresh Button that destroys and recreates Text MediaPlayer (Hangs)!

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer, android-contextmenu, recreate

viewPager4 Fragment Activities

If I click on the Texts that play short sounds, one after another then after sometimes the mediaplayer hangs and doesn't play any sound. But if I'm able to destroy activity and recreate the same activity with refresh button in Action Bar, I'd be able to click sounds again.

So what to write in the code for `R.id.item2`?

Or there is any other way that continuous clicking on short sounds by these texts is possible without any hang kind of problem?

Following is the reference code:

```
public class module1 extends FragmentActivity {
static Context con;
static int length = 0;
ViewPager mViewPager;
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
static MediaPlayer mediaplayer, mediaplayert, m;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    con = this;
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);       
}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mains, menu);
    //  Just .main into .mains [created new for different behavior of Action Bar]       
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(in);
    }   
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {


        //what should i write here? to destroy and recreate the same fragment activity again.
        //Problem: After clicking fast on one after another text links, mediaplayert hangs and doesnt play
        //Solution: exit app destroy and reopen, then mediaplayer works fine... 
        //SO, what to write here? kindly help!


        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}          







public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment ff = new DummySectionFragment1();
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            ff = new DummySectionFragment1();
            break;
        }
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment1.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, arg0 + 1);
        ff.setArguments(args);
        return ff;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int arg0) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section27).toUpperCase(l);          
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class DummySectionFragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public DummySectionFragment1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m01set01, container, false);
        // Genius Shot by Stupid vIC//

                    TextView Text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    Text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            mediaplayert = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.con,
                                    R.raw.sound1);
                            mediaplayert.start();

                        }
                    });







                    TextView Text1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                    Text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            mediaplayert = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.con,
                                    R.raw.sound2);
                            mediaplayert.start();

                        }
                    });

                    TextView Text2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                    Text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            mediaplayert = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.con,
                                    R.raw.sound3);
                            mediaplayert.start();

                        }
                    });


    return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    if (mediaplayert != null) {
        mediaplayert.stop();
        mediaplayert= null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```